# UPSERT syntax inside a function with an UNIQUE constraint on a composite of two columns in a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to use UPSERT syntax inside a function on a table containing an unique constraint on a composite of two columns but I receive an error saying that "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification".

What is strange is that the very same query works fine outside a function!

So, let's say I have a following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  id SERIAL,
  col1 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  col2 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(col1, col2)
);
```

Now I can do an insert like that (and it works fine):

```
INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) VALUES('val1', 'val2')
  ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING id;

-- Output: id integer
1
```

So now I want to use this query inside a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(col1 VARCHAR, col2 VARCHAR)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
  #variable_conflict use_variable
  DECLARE
    rowid INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) VALUES(col1, col2)
    ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id INTO rowid;
  RETURN rowid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

But when I call the function I get the error:

```
SELECT test_func('val1', 'val2');

    ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) VALUES(col1, col2)
    ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id"
PL/pgSQL function test_func(character varying,character varying) line 6 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
SQL state: 42P10
Context: SQL statement "INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) VALUES(col1, col2)
    ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id"
PL/pgSQL function test_func(character varying,character varying) line 6 at SQL statement
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Rename your parameters to e.g. `p_col1, p_col2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, you were right! I find the error message misleading.